# a problem of the dual of a normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis

If the dual of a normed vector space X, say X*, is separable, then the normed space X itself is separable. How to prove it?

And if the normed space $X$ is separable, then its dual $X^*$ is separable, too?

Comment: ,See Corollary 1.11.17, p. 104; Megginson, Robert E. (1998), An introduction to Banach space theory.

Comment: You start with a countable dense subset in $X^\ast$ (or in a suitable subset of $X^\ast$) and from that construct a countable subset of $X$ whose linear span is dense. The answer to the second question is "not necessarily".